# Android: how to encapsulate layout.xml in Object

Tags: android, android-layout

I have layout file which I'm inflating dynamically on the screen.
Then in my activity I have to init some UI logic (listeners, etc...).

But now this logic needs to be moved to some class. And I can't decide what way is the best to create view based object that has its layout in xml.

```
public MyView extends View {
    MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        //inflation here...        
    }
```

OR

```
MyViewFactory {
    View get(Inflater inflater) {

    }
```

OR something else?

May be someone can also recommend source code where to look for.

Comment: So if you're inflating your layout, why are you not doing that in your activity? If the information you need is in your activity, build your layout dynamically there and set your UI logic there. The activity class already has several useful methods for doing exactly that. Take a look at the [activity documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Comment: Can you name theese methods ?

Comment: First question: what precisely is this layout for? Is it the general layout of your entire activity, or is it a sub-layout that you would like to navigate to after some type of user interaction?

Comment: What you are looking for is a compound control - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want to do this with a simple view like ImageView. you want it to be a more complex layout like (linear layout containing buttons etc)?

In case you need the first you are best off with a simple view instance like `ImageView img = new ImageView(context);` or a factory if you have more parameters involved if you think its simpler setting them in xml.

As far as more complex layouts go i prefer using a custom class extending some of the viewGroups(**Like:** `MyView extends LinearLayout`)

create a function called `init();`

call the function from each constructor

implement inside it something like:

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_layout,this,true);
```

**this** + **true** would mean that the layout will be attached to the root, in this case linearLayout and you can use findViewById directly on the viewgroup)

```
ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.myView);
```

i find it really important to create custom views since they always include logic that is specific to them and can be reused and also expose some public methods to invoke from the activities that include the custom view.

Comment: It would be a complex layout, with buttons and other controls.

Comment: Then my solution is what you need :). it will show in advanced views and you can drag it inside the layout.

Comment: Thanks ! But i have trouble with 'this' parameter in inflate method. I wanted to use my object as not root, e.g. call addView(new MyCustomView())
So as far as I understand I have to pass into constructor root view, and pass this view into method instead of this. Am I correct ?

Comment: basically in this case the root is not the root of the whole hierarchy but only for the hierarchy for the views inside the custom view. This refers in this case to your root but you can skip that and just use View v = inflater.inflate(r.layout.some,null). this will return the view from xml and you can add it afterwards.